# How to consume custom fields in RSS feeds

Tags: views, feeds

I'm sharing data between two Drupal sites using the Aggregator and Views modules. This works, but the source server places CCK fields within the description field; when I try to use those fields in the destination view (for example, to filter content), the view doesn't render the CCK fields.

Is there any way to make the CCK fields render as regular fields in the RSS, like title or author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this situation I prefer using the [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module, then enable a rest server and using the index. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the same callback code.